# Why is my SQL Database not recognizing my 2nd and 3rd tables as relational tables, despite recognizing the 1st?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very new to SQL and I am having difficulties working on my project for school. I have 3 tables: material, costs, and usages. I can only query the "material" table (used a SELECT * FROM statement to display everything), but when I try it on my other tables, it says  ERROR: relation "costs" does not exist. I am completely stumped. I posted the raw code and an image for legibility. Any help is greatly appreciated. I do not know too much about SQL as a whole, but I also am following my teacher's project example, and syntactically speaking, it is setup the exact same way, which is why I am at a loss as to why only one of my three tables are accessible.

```
CREATE DATABASE equipment;
CREATE USER equipment WITH PASSWORD 'testing';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE equipment to equipment;
\c equipment

CREATE TABLE material (
          material_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
          name            VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
          description     VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          tensile_strength INTEGER NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY     ( material_id )
);

CREATE TABLE costs (
          cost_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
          material_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
          price          DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,,
          CONSTRAINT fk_material_id FOREIGN KEY (material_id) REFERENCES material(material_id)
          PRIMARY KEY     ( cost_id )
);

CREATE TABLE usages (
          usage_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
          cost_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
          purpose          VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          location_to_purchase  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_cost_id FOREIGN KEY (cost_id) REFERENCES costs(cost_id)
          PRIMARY KEY ( usage_id )

);

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON material, costs, usages TO equipment;

INSERT INTO material VALUES (0, 'Steel', 'Steel is the highest quality material used on barbells and weight plates in the gym. It has the highest durability, and as such, is typically the most expensive', '205000');
INSERT INTO material VALUES (1, 'Cast Iron', 'Cast Iron is of a notably lesser quality, but is significantly more affordable for gym equipment owners. It is frequently found in all-in-one training equipment sets for young adults', '120000');
INSERT INTO material VALUES (2, 'Bronze', 'Bronze is a material used much less frequently than steel or cast iron, but it is much more attainable and can be used in making custom gym equipment, due to its high affordability', '85000');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (0, 0, '449.52');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (0, 1, '262.73');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (0, 2, '160.41');
INSERT INTO usages (0, 0, 'Used for extremely heavy loads on the barbell with minimal stress exerted on the bar shaft', 'Can be purchased at Rogue Fitness, EliteFTS, Titan Fitness, and small competitors as well');
INSERT INTO usages (1, 1, 'Used for light to moderate loads. Frequently found in beginner training where technique training is the priority. It is also easily replaceable', 'Can be found on Rogue Fitness, Amazon, and re-sell marketplaces such as Craigslist');
INSERT INTO usages (2, 2, 'Used in adolescent training. Bars can be cut to size to be a best fit for the user, and it is even more obtainable than steel or iron since you can buy bronze in bulk', 'Not found on many fitness marketplaces, but can be acquired on material wholesale locations such as the Online Metals website');
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRjmi.png)
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wWvt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of errors

MysqL, has not taht ssyntax for creatig users and Provileges

Every row must have if it is not the last statement a comma which sperates dieffrent columns or constraints

The part with giveing gant to the tables, is so not possible, you can only grant one at a time, or use the sytax equipment.* for all tables

Last yyour last 3 `INSERT INTO` are missing `VALUES` bedore the new contenet

```
CREATE DATABASE equipment;
CREATE USER
  'equipment'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
                                   BY 'testing';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON equipment.* to equipment@localhost;

use equipment;

CREATE TABLE material (
          material_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
          name            VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
          description     VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          tensile_strength INTEGER NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY     ( material_id )
);

CREATE TABLE costs (
          cost_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
          material_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
          price          DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_material_id FOREIGN KEY (material_id) REFERENCES material(material_id),
          PRIMARY KEY     ( cost_id )
);

CREATE TABLE usages (
          usage_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
          cost_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
          purpose          VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          location_to_purchase  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_cost_id FOREIGN KEY (cost_id) REFERENCES costs(cost_id),
          PRIMARY KEY ( usage_id )

);



INSERT INTO material VALUES (0, 'Steel', 'Steel is the highest quality material used on barbells and weight plates in the gym. It has the highest durability, and as such, is typically the most expensive', '205000');
INSERT INTO material VALUES (1, 'Cast Iron', 'Cast Iron is of a notably lesser quality, but is significantly more affordable for gym equipment owners. It is frequently found in all-in-one training equipment sets for young adults', '120000');
INSERT INTO material VALUES (2, 'Bronze', 'Bronze is a material used much less frequently than steel or cast iron, but it is much more attainable and can be used in making custom gym equipment, due to its high affordability', '85000');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (0, 0, '449.52');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (0, 1, '262.73');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (0, 2, '160.41');
INSERT INTO usages VALUES (0, 0, 'Used for extremely heavy loads on the barbell with minimal stress exerted on the bar shaft', 'Can be purchased at Rogue Fitness, EliteFTS, Titan Fitness, and small competitors as well');
INSERT INTO usages VALUES (1, 1, 'Used for light to moderate loads. Frequently found in beginner training where technique training is the priority. It is also easily replaceable', 'Can be found on Rogue Fitness, Amazon, and re-sell marketplaces such as Craigslist');
INSERT INTO usages VALUES (2, 2, 'Used in adolescent training. Bars can be cut to size to be a best fit for the user, and it is even more obtainable than steel or iron since you can buy bronze in bulk', 'Not found on many fitness marketplaces, but can be acquired on material wholesale locations such as the Online Metals website');
```

## FOR postgres the above is still valid except for creating the user, that is a bit different in Mysql

Also costs costs_id is promary key, so you can't enter only 0 in the column

```
CREATE DATABASE equipment;
CREATE USER equipment WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'testing';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE equipment TO equipment;
use equipment;

CREATE TABLE material (
          material_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
          name            VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
          description     VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          tensile_strength INTEGER NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY     ( material_id )
);

CREATE TABLE costs (
          cost_id        INTEGER NOT NULL,
          material_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
          price          DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_material_id FOREIGN KEY (material_id) REFERENCES material(material_id),
          PRIMARY KEY     ( cost_id )
);

CREATE TABLE usages (
          usage_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
          cost_id          INTEGER NOT NULL,
          purpose          VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          location_to_purchase  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT fk_cost_id FOREIGN KEY (cost_id) REFERENCES costs(cost_id),
          PRIMARY KEY ( usage_id )

);

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON material, costs, usages TO equipment;

INSERT INTO material VALUES (0, 'Steel', 'Steel is the highest quality material used on barbells and weight plates in the gym. It has the highest durability, and as such, is typically the most expensive', '205000');
INSERT INTO material VALUES (1, 'Cast Iron', 'Cast Iron is of a notably lesser quality, but is significantly more affordable for gym equipment owners. It is frequently found in all-in-one training equipment sets for young adults', '120000');
INSERT INTO material VALUES (2, 'Bronze', 'Bronze is a material used much less frequently than steel or cast iron, but it is much more attainable and can be used in making custom gym equipment, due to its high affordability', '85000');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (0, 0, '449.52');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (1, 1, '262.73');
INSERT INTO costs VALUES (2, 2, '160.41');
INSERT INTO usages VALUES (0, 0, 'Used for extremely heavy loads on the barbell with minimal stress exerted on the bar shaft', 'Can be purchased at Rogue Fitness, EliteFTS, Titan Fitness, and small competitors as well');
INSERT INTO usages VALUES (1, 1, 'Used for light to moderate loads. Frequently found in beginner training where technique training is the priority. It is also easily replaceable', 'Can be found on Rogue Fitness, Amazon, and re-sell marketplaces such as Craigslist');
INSERT INTO usages VALUES (2, 2, 'Used in adolescent training. Bars can be cut to size to be a best fit for the user, and it is even more obtainable than steel or iron since you can buy bronze in bulk', 'Not found on many fitness marketplaces, but can be acquired on material wholesale locations such as the Online Metals website');
```

Comment: I am using Postgresql, my bad, not mysql.

Comment: that does not matter much, most of the problems are the same i added a postgres version.

Comment: I made the above changes you recommended, but I am still unable to query the costs or usages table.

Comment: do you ge an error`?

Comment: @BigB1225 it works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ecddcf4a930f603e63bec2676990fc0b

Comment: So, I moved the connect statement to equipment to the end of the code, and then everything worked fine together apparently, now, I am faced with these errors. I am confused as to what is set improperly. https://imgur.com/a/dVSuezD